# python web scraping. Site not showing only a few script tags. Have tried opening with selenium driver browser

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull the price from this [site](https://shop.coles.com.au/a/churchill-centre/product/dove-antiperspirant-deodorant-invisible-dry).
I tried with beautifulsoup first then opened page with selenium webdriver browser but got this response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="about:blank">
</head>
<body>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/j.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/f.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint/script/kpf.js?url=/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint&token=9d98d39f-e497-2d15-7332-7e21738bd6e2"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

dove_coles_url = "https://shop.coles.com.au/a/churchill-centre/product/dove-antiperspirant-deodorant-invisible-dry"
PATH = "C:\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get(dove_coles_url)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your browser console, in the network tab, you can see this request being made :

https://shop.coles.com.au/search/resources/store/20509/productview/bySeoUrlKeyword/dove-antiperspirant-deodorant-invisible-dry?catalogId=17056

Opening it you'll see that it contains all the data for this product in json.